# Firebase analytics find custom event parameters

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I create some custom parameter in my android app as the Firebase doc

```
//frist way
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_ITEM) {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "3")
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "requestCargo")
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "text")
}

//second way
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("create_cargo") {
    param("user_id", "1")
    param("action_type", "videoCall")
}
```

1. I can see the event in Firebase -> Analytics -> Event
2. There is no `enable custom events`
3. there is no `custom reporting` tab

[image]

I could not see my params `user_id, action_type`

But I can see that in Firebase -> Analytics -> Realtime

[image]

Please help me if you know how to show params

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the change.

There is a `Custom definitions` in the Analytics menu

You should create your custom definitions on this page

And set the `Event parameter` as your param in your app

[image]

you should wait some hours or a day. after that you can see the result on the `Event` page in your event

[image]

Comment: Been looking for the correct answer for hours, but this is currently (27-08-2021) the only clear and working one.